# Unable to install IIS on Windows 10

Tags: iis, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, dism

I just upgraded my Windows 8 machine to Windows 10 yesterday. I did not have IIS installed at the time (though I've installed it with ease on other machines in the past). I was hoping it would once again be easy, but something seems wrong with Windows 10 and IIS.

I went to Control Panel > Programs > Turn Windows features on or off. I ticked the box for Internet Information Services, and hit OK. The first time I tried this, everything looked like it was going well until it popped up some error dialog (the text of which I cannot recall at the moment). So I did some searching and found a forum post that recommended to run this command from the command line:

```
dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
```

So I gave that a shot (had to do so from a Run-as-Administrator command line), but that got to about 20% and then just stopped moving. So I rebooted the machine and tried from Control Panel again. Now I just get an infinite progress bar inside a window labeled "Windows Features" that says "Searching for required files." It just moves from left to right over and over again, nothing ever happening. How can I get IIS installed in Windows 10?

**EDIT:** That `dism` command finally finished! Here's what it said when it finished:

> The source files could not be found.
>
> Use the "Source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the feature. For more information on specifying source location, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077.
>
> The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log

Comment: "it popped up some error dialog" - without the error message we are just guessing at answers ...

Comment: If I could recreate it I would! My apologies

Answer (score 1):

Wait... it seems to have resolved itself. My apologies. What I described as an "infinite" progress bar was, in fact, finite. It eventually finished, and now IIS is there.

Comment: Took about an hour for me waiting for "_Searching for required files_" and then about 15 minutes waiting for "_Applying changes_".
Not sure if it's true, but the reason could be this one: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsvistanow/2009/02/25/why-it-takes-a-very-long-time-to-turn-on-windows-features-in-vista-through-control-panel/